# Is there any best alternative for this basic calculation in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose, I've a instance `NSInteger` like this,

```
NSInteger height = 100;
```

I want to calculate (full + half) value so I'm doing it like this,

```
NSInteger newHeight = (height + (height/2));
```

Is there any other alternative for this?

<sub>P.S. 100 value is not static, so I can't just take 150 directly. I'll need to calculate it every time.</sub>

Comment: There is always more than one way to skin a cat, so what exactly is your issue with that code?

Comment: Indeed, this Q should be voted as the most substantial Q on SO ever.

Comment: @trojanfoe, yes you're right...I'm not sure how's the my way. I'm looking for something good which should be the best and on the top of other solutions. If any.

Comment: For integers there is no better way.  Move on.

Comment: What if, the same question is for `float` (or `CGFloat`) ?

Comment: Then you would use `height * 1.5f`, as someone has already answered.

Comment: @trojanfoe, yes, so do you think, that will be the best alternative for this?

Comment: It depends if you are using integers or floats.  Your code shows integers.  For floats then use `* 1.5`.  it's not an alternative, however, as the data type is different.  Therefore the "best way" is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSInteger newHeight = 1.5 * height;
```

I cannot find another way which is easier.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert Are you sure? Really, really? Hard to forecast on modern CPUs without knowing the code around. BTW: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. (Donald Knuth)

Comment: I don't think it is generally good for performance to use floating point when integer will do. Generally it is a lot slower even on modern CPUs.

Comment: I think as it is written below, shift and addition is better rather when multiplying floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Utility.h file subclass of NSObject and write on it

```
-(NSInteger)calculate:(NSInteger) height
{
   return (height + (height/2));
}
```

and called where you want to import this file #import"Utility.h"

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it becomes "better", if you omit the unnecessary parentheses:

```
NSInteger newHeight = height + height/2;
```

BTW: This would work, too:

```
NSInteger newHeight = height + height>>1;
```

Comment: If you can't beat 'em, join 'em, eh?

Comment: I think it is better to have the brackets to make your intentions clear even if the compiler just removes them and they make no difference to  the resultant code.

Answer (score 0):

Before compilers got so good at optimizing you would of sped this up by removing the divide operation (as divides were slow) like so:

```
NSInteger newHeight = height + (height>>1);
```

If you dump the generated assembler I would of thought that the original code would end up being changed to this anyway.